# cant figure out how to loop for hangman in python

Tags: python

I am trying to loop over my hangman project but cannot seem to figure out a way without creating an infinite loop. I want to avoid having to ask for user input in multiple places in my guess function and be able to put it in in one place. I feel like I have all the logic down, I would just need to figure out the looping portion. How can I solve this?

```
from random import choice

print('Welcome to Hangman!!!, Guess the secret word ')
user_guess = input('What is your first guess at the secret word?  ')

org_word = choice(['cat','dog','mug','plate'])
word = set(org_word)
already_guessed = ''
chances = 10

def hang_man():
        guess()
        check_win()



def guess():
    global chances
    global correct_letters
    global already_guessed
    #check for valid input
    if len(user_guess) > 1 or user_guess.isnumeric():
        print('you entered an invalid input and you lost a guess')
        chances -= 1
        if chances == 0:
            print('Sorry you are out of guesses, You Lost :(')
        else:
            print(f'you now have {chances} guesses left')
    #check if letter was already guessed
    elif user_guess in already_guessed:
        print('you already entered that letter and you lost a guess')
        chances -=1
    #incorrect guess
    elif user_guess not in word:
        print('That guess was not in the word and you lost a guess')
        chances -= 1
        already_guessed += user_guess
        if chances == 0:
            print('Sorry you are out of guesses, You Lost :(')
        else:
            print(f'you now have {chances} guesses left')
    #correct guess
    elif len(user_guess) == 1 and user_guess in word:
            print(f'Great, your guess of {user_guess} was in the word')
            word.remove(user_guess)


def check_win():
    if len(word) == 0 :
        print(f'Congrats, you guessed the correct word {org_word}')

hang_man()
```

Comment: when you guess the word or your chances become 0 use the `break` keyword inside their respective if condition

Comment: If you loop user_input then it will keep telling the user to input the first chracter

Comment: also if the user inputs a special chracter then your code will do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could amend `check_win()` to return true when guessed correctly:

```
def check_win():
    if len(word) == 0 :
        print(f'Congrats, you guessed the correct word {org_word}')
        return True
```

Then while the word hasn't been guessed:

```
def hang_man():
    while not check_win():
        guess()
```

**Edit:** Thanks for the spot Pranav Hosangadi.

Comment: You don't need the extra call to `check_win()` at the bottom of the `while`.